# How to split pandas record with one large timedelta into multiple records with smaller ones?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 3 columns: timedeltas (duration) of time slot, datetime of slot start and datetime informing when record was created. Timedeltas are all multipliers of 15 minutes:

```
Index    duration    slot_start         creation_time

1.       15 minutes  some datetime 1    some datetime 3
2.       45 minutes  some datetime 2    some datetime 4
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
Index    duration    slot_start                      creation_time

1.       15 minutes  some datetime 1                 some datetime 3
2.       15 minutes  some datetime 2                 some datetime 4
3.       15 minutes  some datetime 2 + 15 minutes    some datetime 4
4.       15 minutes  some datetime 2 + 30 minutes    some datetime 4
```

Is there any tool for such operation? How to achieve it easily and time efficiently on very large dataframes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
unit = pd.Timedelta(minutes=15)
s = pd.to_timedelta(df['duration']).div(unit) \
      .apply(lambda n: unit * np.arange(n)) \
      .rename('offset') \
      .explode()

df = df.join(s)
df['slot_start'] = df['slot_start'] + df['offset']
```

Comment: That is quite good idea, but it won't add time differences in slot_start, which is crucial.

Comment: Sorry that I missed the second requirement. Updated my answer

Comment: Brilliant answer! One important note: This solution requires Pandas version higher than 0.25. On earlier versions explode will cause errors.